# Mostrar informacion segun el usuario logueado, clase ListView? - Django

Tags: python, django

## models.py

```
class Torneo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=200)

  def __str__(self):
     return (self.descripcion)
```

## views.py

```
 class Torneo_ListView(ListView):    
     template_name = 'torneos/torneo_listar.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Torneo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me sale este error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que te muestra indica que la identación de código está mal. En el código que posteas la identación está mal en ambas clases , no se si es resultado de copiar el código o lo tienes así originalmente. Si usas identado de 4 espacios que es lo recomendado en [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) debería ser así:

**models.py**

```
class Torneo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.descripcion)
```

**views.py**

```
class Torneo_ListView(ListView):    
    template_name = 'torneos/torneo_listar.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Torneo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Vigila también que no estes mezclando espacios y tabulaciones para identar el código.

Comment: Fue al copiar, en el codigo las tengo bien. Mira me guie por esto https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering y no consigo que me de.

Comment: @jhonperez si usas Python2.x y sobretodo si has copiado y pegado código asegurate que TODO tu código en el script usa espacios o tabulaciones para identar (nunca mezclar ambas). Si ese es todo tu `views.py` crea un nuevo script, copia el código de mi respuesta o reescribelo a mano y sustituye al anterior por el nuevo script y prueba a ver. Aunque visualmete esté identado al mismo nivel este error es típico por copiar código identado con tabulaciones y añadir alguna linea a mano con un editor que identa con espacios (o viceversa)

Comment: Increible de verdad que por cosas como esas se presenten estos tipos de errores , gracias de verdad bro , se me llevo un buen rato en eso.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general, un proyecto estándar se crea con algunas configuraciones *"de fábrica"*, entre ellas en la sección de plantillas, se incluye el procesador [`django.template.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request) que proporciona **la variable globlal** **`resquest`**.

No forma parte de tu *objeto*, en este caso, no forma parte de la clase `Torneo_ListView`, por lo que **no debes** llamarlo desde `self`.

Asi las cosas, este código debería funcionar.

```
 class Torneo_ListView(ListView):    
     template_name = 'torneos/torneo_listar.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Torneo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

> ### Nota
>
> Es importante que te asegures que tienes los procesadores correspondientes. Verifica en tu archivo de configuración `settings.py` que tengas algo parecido a esto:
>
> ```
>   TEMPLATES = [
>       {
>           # algunas otras opciones 
>           'OPTIONS': {
>               # Otras opciones 
>               'context_processors': [
>                   # ... 
>                   # muchos procesadores.... 
>                   'django.template.context_processors.request',
>                   # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>                   # este debe estar presente
>               ],
>           },
>       },
>   ]
> ```

Comment: Don @toledano verifique lo que dice en la nota y todo en orden y quite el self. Pero aun se sigue presentando el error.

Comment: @jhonperez, edita tu pregunta y especifica el error que comentas.

Comment: es el mismo del screen (IndentationError: expected an indented block)

Answer (score 0):

El problema de la indentación es por el uso de espacios en vez de tabulaciones, pero, a mi me ha pasado que aun usando tabulaciones, me lo detecta como espacios.

Solución: Instalate el editor de textos Sublime Text 3, abre el archivo con ese editor, y en el menú dale a: View -> Indentation -> Convert indentations to Tabs.

Asi se te quitan los errores de indentación de todas las lineas.